# How to use Google's official Spark BigQuery connector on partitioned tables?

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I'm using [Google's official Spark-BigQuery connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example) (`com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:bigquery-connector:hadoop2-0.13.6`) to retrieve data from BigQuery on a huge **time-partitioned table** (field `myDateField`).

So I'm currently doing this (example adapted from the docs) to retrieve recent data (less than a month) :

```scala
val config = sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
config.set(BigQueryConfiguration.GCS_BUCKET_KEY, "mybucket")
val fullyQualifiedInputTableId = "project:dataset.table"
BigQueryConfiguration.configureBigQueryInput(config, fullyQualifiedInputTableId)

val bigQueryRDD: RDD[(LongWritable, JsonObject)] = sparkSession.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    config,
    classOf[GsonBigQueryInputFormat],
    classOf[LongWritable],
    classOf[JsonObject]
)

val convertedRDD: RDD[MyClass] = bigQueryRDD.map { case (_, jsonObject) =>
    convertJsonObjectToMyClass(jsonObject)
}

val recentData: RDD[MyClass] = convertedRDD.filter { case MyClass(_, myDateField) =>
    myDateField >= "2018-08-10"
}

println(recentData.count())
```

### Questions

- I'm wondering if the connector queries **all data** from the BigQuery table, like :

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ```

  Or if it does something clever (and more important, less expensive) that use partitioning like :

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE myDateField >= TIMESTAMP("2018-08-10")
  ```
- moreover, in general, how can I control the costs of a query and be sure that irrelevant data (here, data before `"2018-08-10"` for example) is not retrieved for nothing?
- in case BigQuery retrieves all data, can I provide a specific query? `BigQueryConfiguration.INPUT_QUERY_KEY` (`mapred.bq.input.query`) is deprecated, but I don't see any replacement and the docs are not very clear on that

Comment: _Or if it does something clever_ - It doesn't. Once you operate on `RDD` `filter { ... }` it is completely detached from the source, and no information is passed upstream.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but is there any way to directly retrieve only useful data without using `filter`?

Comment: You might want to dig into https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery, though it is not longer actively developed.

Comment: I made some tests with that lib, but it has also some drawbacks : only legacy SQL supported + the scary fact that it's in "maintenance mode". Anyway, it's such a shame that the official connector does not support querying partitioned tables...